# Laravel 5.4 hash::check() returns false

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to validate a user's old password before the update runs to confirm a password change. But i am constantly getting a `false` response.

Get the supplied 'old password' from the form

```
$old_password = $request->old_password;
```

Get the current user

```
$user = $this->getUser($request->id);
```

Check the password against password saved in database

```
dd($this->checkPassword($request->old_password, $user->password));
```

> returns false in browser.

```
protected function getUser($id)
{
    return User::find($id);
}


protected function checkPassword($password, $current)
{
    return (bool) (Hash::check($password, $current) === 1);
}
```

Comment: You can easily check like: `$check_password = Hash::check($request->old_password, $user->password);  dd($check_password);`

Comment: I believe `Hash::check` returns boolean already... comparing with `=== 1` will return false regardless. Your function should just `return Hash::check($password, $current);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hash::check` returns a boolean already.

Your method compares with the result with === 1 which will return false regardless. `===` compares the type too, which compares (boolean) true/false with (integer) 1 which will never be true.

Your function should just return `Hash::check($password, $current);`

```
protected function checkPassword($password, $current)
{
    return Hash::check($password, $current);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the example below :

```
    $user = Auth::user();

    $oldPass = $request->input('old_password');

    if(Hash::check(  $oldPass ,  $user->password) )
    {
        // is Match Password
    }
    else
    {
        // not Match
    }
```